# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when connecting to maridb

Tags: mariadb

strong textwhen connecting to mariadb database connection is not happening

need to connect with the data base.

## HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
Failed to initialize pool: null

HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists customers
HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null